How to proceed when the journal does not provide a template?
I am working on publishing a review article in the Journal of Medical Internet Research or JMIR. However, I cannot find any templates that can be used to format the paper easily. LaTex templates are not available and not accepted either. What can I do? Does this mean that I have to manually format my paper according to their guidelines?

Since the journal is in a medical field, I wouldn't expect the production staff to know how to handle LaTeX submissions in the first place. You can ask before submission, of course, but the simpler (and more likely to work) method is to just go with the format(s) they explicitly support. In this and many other journals, that means MS Word. There is a link to a Word template from the Instructions for Authors page.

thank you so much. Really appreciate it.
